# Where to receive watch notifications for gmail in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, push-notification, gmail-api, google-cloud-pubsub

I'm trying to receive watch notification for Gmail mailboxes in my .NET C# program.

I have the following code:

```
WatchRequest body = new WatchRequest()
{
    LabelIds = labelIds,
    TopicName = PrivateKeys.GoogleGmailTopic
};

WatchResponse response = new UsersResource.WatchRequest(_gmailService, body, "me")
{
    Key = PrivateKeys.GoogleApiKey,
    OauthToken = AccessToken
}
    .Execute();
```

... and it seems to work, since I get a response.

But **where do I receive these notifications inside my program**? How can I configure the event entry point?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you did the preliminary work to set up a Cloud Pub/Sub client (described here: https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/push#initial_cloud_pubsub_setup), you should have a Pub/Sub subscription - either PULL or PUSH.

In order to get the notifications, your application should initiate a subscriber, you can follow the instructions in https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/pull for PULL or in https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/push for PUSH. Configuring the event entry point should be done as part of the subscriber set up.